# One line for loops that don't require list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, output, one-liner

I'm trying to figure out how the one line for statement works when the output is not meant to be a list. For example, if I want to print these tuples of matching x to x+10, I have the code:

```
[print((i2x, xi2xx)) for i2x, xi2xx in zip(range(1,11), range(11,21))]
```

which outputs

```
(1, 11)
(2, 12)
(3, 13)
(4, 14)
(5, 15)
(6, 16)
(7, 17)
(8, 18)
(9, 19)
(10, 20)
>>> [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Now I think I understand that the print statement (which I am treating as a command) is executed within the for loop, but I was wondering if this bracketed list of `None` is a necessary output for a one line for loop. A multiline for loop for this would look like:

```
for i2x, xi2xx in zip(range(1,11), range(11,21)):
    print((i2x, xi2xx))
```

which only outputs

```
(1, 11)
(2, 12)
(3, 13)
(4, 14)
(5, 15)
(6, 16)
(7, 17)
(8, 18)
(9, 19)
(10, 20)
```

Am I missing something about how the brackets work in the oneline statement?  Is there a way to only output a print statement without the list of `None`?

Comment: Exactly like your second example is the way to do this.

Comment: Comprehensions are typically used to create a useful object. While it works here and produces this useless output, the classical loop should be preferred.

Comment: The "one line for statement" is a *list comprehension* and by definition it creates a list of values. It should not be misused for side effects like printing.

Comment: For what it's worth, you *can* do this in a single line without the list comprehension: `print(*zip(range(1,11), range(11,21)), sep='\n')`. I think most python devs would prefer the `for` loop for readability.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the product of your code:

```
[print((i2x, xi2xx)) for i2x, xi2xx in zip(range(1,11), range(11,21))]
```

is the list created by the list comprehension (since you are using the square brackets).

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

The list comprehensions, work the following way: It appends (inserts in the end of the list) the first thing you write, in your case `print((i2x, xi2xx))` to the list, but since, as you said, one could treat print statement as a command, every time it will not add any value in the list but None.
So as a result you get the list of None values.

So if we write:

```
lst_comp = [x for x in range(10)]

print(lst_comp)
```

the output would be:

```
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

It's different from the for loop, it is the list comprehension, it returns list, I believe that one could not call it oneline for loop...

It would be the same if we wrote:

```
lst_comp = []

for x in range(10):
    lst_comp.append(x)

print(lst_comp)
```